# Using Epplus to generate xlsx with nested list

Tags: c#, epplus

I am using EPPlus to generate a xlsx document.

My model below includes a `List<string>` and this is where things got complicated for me:

```
                var tableBody = worksheet.Cells["B2:B2"].LoadFromCollection(
                    from f in saaOperators.OrderBy(x => x.Identifier).Where(t => t.Identifier.StartsWith(worksheet.Name) ||

                    (t.Identifier.StartsWith("W") && worksheet.Name.Equals("BIR")))

                    from u in f.Units

                    select new { f.Identifier, f.Name, f.Profile, u }, true);
```

If I am doing `select new {f.Identifier, f.Name, f.Profile, f.Units }` it returns only the first item in the `Units` list.

If I am doing `select new { f.Identifier, f.Name, f.Profile, u }` for every item in `Units` it creates new rows with duplicate `Identifier`, `Name` and `Profile`.

Here is my model class:

```
public class SaaOperator
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Profile { get; set; }
    public List<string> Units { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

What is the proper way to identify cells with the same value for `Identifier`, `Name` and `Profile` and merge them?

For example, in the screenshot below I need to merge `B3:B4`, `B5:B6`, `C3:C4`, `C5:C6`, `D3:D4`, `D5:D6.`

I know I can use `worksheet.Cells["B3:B4"].Merge = true;`, but I need a way to programatically identify the start and end cell with the same value.

**EDIT 1:** Added a screenshot with duplicated values. [image: duplicated values.]

**EDIT 2** - Based on Ernie's comment, I need a way to programatically search the worksheet for cells with the same value and merge them.

Comment: This is enough for someone to guess at what you want the output to be, but it's uncertain enough that we're likely to guess wrong. Do you want to display the first value for `Units` along with corresponding values for `Identifier`, `Name`, and `Profile`, and then leave those three cells blank for the other units to avoid repeating them?

Comment: Hi Scott, I want to display all values in `Units` along with corresponding values for `Identifier`, `Name` and `Profile`, not just the first value. I am guessing I should merge the duplicated rows/cells `Identifier`, `Name`, `Profile` if there are multiple `units` for an operator.

Comment: When you say, "Not the first value," what is the first value you don't want to display? This would be easier if you posted a sample of what this would look like. I suspect that I know what you mean so I'll take a stab at it.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to see values which gets duplicated.

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you are expecting in the output.  If each operator has multiple `Units` then you are not getting duplicate rows, you are in fact getting distinct row - its just that the `u` column that is the only one that will different.  If you do `f.Units` then I assume you are get a `ToString()` output in the columns, i.e.`System.Collections.Generic.List``1[System.String]`.  Post what is is you need exported maybe so we can better understand.

Comment: @Ernie In fact you are right, I guess this is the expected output. Maybe the proper way to resolve my issue is to merge cells with duplicate information, and keep only the U column, when an operator has multiple `units`. Is there a way to search the worksheet for repetetive values, find their row and column number and merge them? I know I can use `worksheet.Cells["B3:B4"].Merge = true;` but I do not know how to identify cells with duplicate information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, I would avoid the `LoadFromCollection` method and do a traditional `for` since what you are doing is too specific.  And I would also avoid trying to merge cells since that makes thing unnecessarily complicated.  This should do it:

```
var data = saaOperators
    .Where(t => t.Identifier.StartsWith(worksheet.Name) || (t.Identifier.StartsWith("W") && worksheet.Name.Equals("BIR")))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Identifier)
    .ToList();

var r = 2;

worksheet.Cells[r, 1].Value = "Identifier";
worksheet.Cells[r, 2].Value = "Name";
worksheet.Cells[r, 3].Value = "Profile";
worksheet.Cells[r, 4].Value = "Unit";
r++;

for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    var op = data[i];
    worksheet.Cells[r + i, 1].Value = op.Identifier;
    worksheet.Cells[r + i, 2].Value = op.Name;
    worksheet.Cells[r + i, 3].Value = op.Profile;

    if (!op.Units.Any())
        continue;

    for (var j = 0; j < op.Units.Count; j++)
        worksheet.Cells[r + i + j, 4].Value = op.Units[j];

    r += op.Units.Count - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

Given a `List<SaaOperator>` or other `IEnumerable<SaaOperator>`:

```
foreach (var saaOperator in saaOperators)
{
    string[] valuesToDisplay;
    for (var x = 0; x < saaOperator.Units.Count; x++)
    {
        if (x == 0) // show all the properties
            valuesToDisplay = new[]
                {saaOperator.Identifier, 
                 saaOperator.Name, 
                 saaOperator.Profile, 
                 saaOperator.Units[x]};
        else // after the first unit, don't repeat the other properties
            valuesToDisplay = new[]
                {"", "", "", saaOperator.Units[x]};
    }
}
```

In other words,

- iterate over all of the items in the list
- for each item, iterate over all of the values in the `Units` list.
- If it's the first item, display all the properties. If it's not the first item, only display the unit.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution, unfortunately I am not able to get it work. Newing `valuesToDisplay` after each iteration results in displaying only the last `saaOperator` and its properties.